# How is the Airflow Superuser different from a standard user?

Tags: airflow

I have been setting up Apache Airflow over the past few days as a way to manage dependencies across our platform. In order to secure the web ui, I have implemented OAuth authentication.

Authentication works, it logs the user in appropriately and then creates a user record for them.

One thing I don't understand is the significance of the 'Superuser' privilege - does it actually do anything?

When a user logs in for the first time, their account is created. On first log in, the account does not have super user privilege. However they are able to go to 'Users' in the UI and then make themselves a 'Superuser'. That doesn't make sense to me, also having this privilege does not appear to grant any more access to elements of the UI than a standard user.

Is it suppose to work like this?

Answer (score 0):

I use password authorization and in that case difference is that Admin drop-down menu contains only Variables for simple users, but the rest for superuser. [image]